# Push Notification Using Google Cloud Functions and Google Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have an android **Client Application** and and **Admin Application** using Firebase. Whenever a user registers in Client Application, I need to send a push notification to Admin app. I am trying to use `Cloud Functions for Firebase`. I have exported the function, and i can see that on firebase console as well.

[image]

This is my **index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendMessageToAdmin = functions.database.ref('/tokens/users/{userId}/{regToken}').onWrite(event => {

  if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  const userId = event.params.userId;
  const regToken = event.params.regToken;

  // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'You have a new User.',
        body: `${userId} is the id.`,
      }
    };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(regToken, payload);
});
```

Here is my database structure at firebase :

[image]

If i use any online portal to send push or even FCM to send push to admin app for testing purpose, i am receiving the push. But this Cloud Function is not sending the push. Can someone guide me whats wrong i am doing.

**EDIT**

If i change the function to the following , then it works. But i am still wondering why the above function didn't work.

```
exports.sendMessageToAdmin = functions.database.ref('/tokens/users/{userId}').onWrite(event => {


  if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  const userId = event.params.userId;
  var eventSnapshot = event.data;
  const regToken = eventSnapshot.child("regToken").val();

   Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'You have a new User.',
        body: `${userId} is the id.`,
      }
    };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(regToken, payload);
});
```

Comment: Are you receiving a success or error response?

Comment: Add a log statement and look for the output in the Logs pane of the Firebase Console: `console.log('userId:', userId, ' token: ', regToken);`

Comment: What does your Firebase log output say? You can find it in the Firebase console under `Functions -> Logs`

Comment: `userId: 123456793 token: regToken`
This is the log, regToken value is missing

Comment: I guess, i am accessing the regToken value in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you have:

```
const regToken = event.params.regToken;
```

`event.params.regToken` does not return the value of `regToken` it returns the value of the [wildcard path segment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#params) in your reference.